# NoScript hotkeys in Firefox Quantum

Tags: firefox, noscript

I'm new to NoScript, and Firefox Quantum (57) is the first browser I'm using it in. I've noticed on the page https://noscript.net/features that there should be some NoScript hotkeys and `about:config` entries. However it seems that these shortcuts don't work in Firefox 57. Is there a breakage?

Comment: Noscript had to be rewritten for Quantum and is currently lacking many features of the previous version.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the relevant part of the [source code](https://github.com/hackademix/noscript/blob/master/src/manifest.json)

It looks like only two keyboard shortcuts are defined: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to open the NoScript window, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to toggle permissions. The latter, however, seems to conflict with Firefox's default binding for 'restore closed tab'.

Answer (score 0):

The new shortcut for NoScript 10 popup is **Alt+Shift+N**

https://hackademix.net/2017/11/23/noscript-1012-temporary-allow-all-and-more/

This is not yet reflected in the documentation. Not mentioned is a shortcut to temporarily set all page to trusted.